# How does Generator.prototype.throw() work? Is an implicit next() included?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning about `Generator.prototype.throw()`, and I test the code below.

```
var generator = function* () {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
      var value = yield i;
      console.log(i);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("catch exception...");
    }
  }
};

var g = generator();
g.throw();
```

In this case, an error will be thrown saying "Uncaught undefined..." under `chrome v49`.

However, if we invoke `g.next()` firstly, then invoke `g.throw()`, it works.

```
var generator = function* () {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
      var value = yield i;
      console.log(i);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("catch exception...");
    }
  }
};

var g = generator();
g.next(); // Object {value: 0, done: false}
g.throw(); // catch exception...
g.next();
// 1
// Object {value: 2, done: false}
```

In the meantime, the `i` value has been skipped as if `g.next()` was also executed.

How does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `next()` and `throw()` continue where you left. In your first example this would be before your first line:

```
-> throw() for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Therefore the error is not caught. In your second example this would be after the yield:

```
var value = yield i; -> throw()
```

Since the error gets caught, the application continues to the same point. After calling `next()` the application resumes from there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I thought `throw()` would also enter the body of Generator function. I guess I was wrong...